# Mail.ru IMAP: Unsupported search criterion

Tags: mail.ru, imap

Пытаюсь сделать поиск писем через IMAP на Mail.ru, сервер практически на все стандартные критерии поиска (FROM, SUBJECT итд.) отвечает `Unsupported search criterion`.

С любыми другими серверами (GMail, Yahoo Mail, Outlook.com, итд.) проблем не возникает.

Получается Mail.ru не во состоянии адекватно реализовать протокол IMAP? Официальной информации не нашел, может кто-то сталкивался?

Можно конечно делать поиск по работающим критериям, и фильтровать по остальным на клиенте, но при 2000+ писем в ящике это не вариант.

Comment: Январь 2023 Mail.ru по прежнему не поддерживает критерии поиска IMAP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вчера задавал такой вопрос техподдержке mail.ru

Вот что ответили:
"К сожалению, поддержка указанной функции на данный момент не реализована."

А как письма искать не поведали? Я спросил, пока не ответили.

Comment: Спасибо, я тоже отписал в тех. поддержку, печально.

Comment: По поводу поиска: есть ряд критериев (например UNSEEN, SINCE), которые все же работают. Вариант только один, использовать их, а остальные фильтры реализовывать на клиенте. Еще можно попробовать интегрировать поиск через сайт (результаты поиска там возвращает в json) и использовать информацию оттуда для загрузки писем.

Comment: В принятом ответе всё правильно сказано: майлру не поддерживает столь важные функции поиска писем в своих почтовых ящиках. Сейчас на дворе май месяц 2020 года - ситуация не изменилась, увы.

Comment: Январь 2021. Mail.ru по прежнему не поддерживает критерии поиска IMAP. Error: Unsupported search criterion: TO

Comment: Февраль 2021. Всё то же самое - базовые TO, FROM не поддерживаются

Comment: Апрель 2021. [Все тоже самое =(](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ty2FVORVTQM)

Comment: Стоит ли говорить о том, что в августе 2021 ничего не изменилось?)

Comment: Апрель 2022, всё то же самое)

Comment: Июнь 2022 - пока тишина )

Comment: Март 2023 - тоже столкнулись с ошибкой

Comment: 29 апреля 2023. Тоже отмечусь =)