# imap_search не ищет по полю FROM

Tags: php, imap, mail.ru

Доброго времени суток.
Возникла проблема.

```
$mails1=imap_search($mbox, 'FROM '.$login, SE_UID);
```

Собственно. Фрезультат - FALSE. Хотя письма от $login в ящике однозначно есть.
Как с помощью imap_search найти нужные письма?

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто. Mail.ru не поддерживает критерий `FROM`.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Нашёл вот здесь, [http://www.cyberforum.ru/post7177414.html]

Comment: Здесь уже был вопрос по IMAP поиску: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/289544/mail-ru-imap-unsupported-search-criterion . В обсуждении упоминался отрицательный ответ службы поддержки mail.ru